# How should I cluster my data and then run separate algotithms on each cluster?

Tags: r, regression, clustering

I'm new to statistics and R. So, I have a dataset on which I want to build a predictive model.

Since there is quite a variability in the input variables, I thought it would be better to cluster my data first (using kmeans) and then build separate models on each cluster (e.g. Random Forest). Using 10-fold cross-validation the results look very good however I'm not sure if what I'm doing is correct.

Firstly, I cluster my data using kmeans but **I'm also using the dependent variable as well**. Then I fit separate models to each cluster and perform that 10-fold CV for each cluster separately. What if I had a new data point? How would I assign it to a cluster (since I won't have the value of the dependent variable)? Would it be more correct to cluster my initial data without using the dependent variable?

Comment: Welcome to our site! It seems you already know the answer to your question: if your model uses values that won't be available for prediction, then there is no way you can apply it, can you?

Comment: I just hoped I was doing it right because the results were very good (too good to be true)!! Thanks for you help!!